# javascript jira-client package: how to specify a port when setting the host

Tags: javascript, jira-rest-api

The jira-client works fine when not specifying a port, but I need to get to a Jira instance that uses a port.  Anyone know how to do this?  Maybe an env variable?

```
const JiraApi = require('jira-client');
const jira = new JiraApi({
    protocol: 'https',
    host: 'greenhopper.app.company.com:8080',
    ...
});
```

Unfortunately, the library reports the error:

> cause: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND greenhopper.app.company.com:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the port when creating the Jira client

```
jira = new JiraApi({
    protocol: 'https',
    host: config.host,
    port: config.port, // Here
    apiVersion: 'latest',
    strictSSL: true,
    oauth: oauthConfig
});
```

Here are all the options from the [code-jira-client docs](https://jira-node.github.io/typedef/index.html#static-typedef-JiraApiOptions)

Comment: Thanks much.  The port option was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @cmulzer please accept the answer if it solved your problem